# Cross-domain issue in Firefox addon using file:// protocol

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, cross-domain

I have recently windows application which maintains database of passwords each user can download their files and store in local drive obvious we are not allowing them to access this application everytime. its a server application and have client application chrome extension which reads this local file and list all passwords to take over tab and fill username and password. It works perfectly.

Now I am trying to develop similar client application for Firefox to do the same. I am try to access this file from local drive it wont allow me to do so using file protocol.

I have spend almost 8 hours on research over cross - domain functionality but no luck

below is the code is still working fine in chrome extension.

```
function readTextFile(file)
{
    var key = localStorage.getItem("_login");
    var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
    rawFile.open("GET", file, false);
    rawFile.onreadystatechange = function ()
    {
        if(rawFile.readyState === 4)
        {
            if(rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status == 0)
            {
              var fullresponse = decrypt(rawFile.responseText,key);
              var username = fullresponse.split("|")[1];
              var userdata = fullresponse.split("|")[0];
              $("#username").text(username);
              if (fullresponse.length>0){
                $('#jstree_demo_div').html(userdata);
                $('#jstree_demo_div').jstree();
              }else{
                $('#jstree_demo_div').html("Password Database is not found");
              }
            }else{
              $('#jstree_demo_div').html("Password Database is not found");
            }
        }else{

        }
    }
    rawFile.send(null);
}
```

and produce below image result.

[image]

When I using same function in Firefox ad-don it wont work and constantly giving me cross domain warning.

Comment: In Chrome to allow the extension access to local files you need to enable the corresponding switch on chrome://extensions page. In Firefox extension can access local files by default, which is rather a huge security hole, but you need to use fetch('file:///foo', {mode: 'same-origin'}), not XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: `which is rather a huge security hole` - why? nobody installs extensions without knowing what they can do, do they? I though firefox users were enlightened and smarter than Chrome drones :p

Comment: Thanks for response @wOxxOm. I have tried fetch process. it give me error: TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.

I am trying to access ("file:///C://password.pwd");

Note this extension I build for internal use not to publish over internet.

Comment: You're using an invalid path, probably. The correct one would be file:///C:/password.pwd

Comment: Still the same error ..